# Only allow some classes to call a method in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, visibility

Lets say I have a structure like this:

Object A contains an instance of Object B
Object B contains an instance of Object C

Object D extends Object C

I have an instance of object D that other people will be writing and using in my program.  There is some information about that object that I want to have but not give them access to though.  What I am currently doing is storing that information and methods in Object B which contains Object D instead of Object C.

The problem is if I make it private so that Object D can not use any of the methods, then I can not access them from anywhere else in the program either.  Is there any way to make it so that D can not access a method but other classes can?

Comment: You might want to look into the [facade pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern).

Comment: Hmm, I don't quite see how that would work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, you probably want to decouple an abstraction from implementation, so that you can change implementation in the future.

You can do that by implementing [Bridge Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern).

***EDIT***

To answer your comment:
You cannot call CircleShape's public method directly. DrawingAPI's concrete implementations (i.e. DrawingAPI1) should not have any idea about sheer existence of CircleShape class. If you somehow need to call some method of the caller, just define another interface and pass the reference of the caller to callee:

```
public interface CircleInfo {
  Color getBorderColor();
  /* some other methods */
}

public class CircleShape implements Shape, CircleInfo {
  public Color getBorderColor() {
    return Colors.Black; // not sure if it works, just an example
  }

  public void draw() {
    drawingAPI.drawCircle(x, y, radius, this);
  }   

  /* Other methods implementation here */
}

// DrawingAPI modification
interface DrawingAPI {
  public void drawCircle(double x, double y, double radius, CircleInfo info);
}

// Concrete implementation
class DrawingAPI1 implements DrawingAPI {
  public void drawCircle(double x, double y, double radius, CircleInfo info) {
    System.out.printf("API1.circle at %f:%f radius %f color %s\n",
      x, y, radius, info.getBorderColor().toString());
}
```

Comment: Hmm, looking at their example on that page and it seems like it might work.  Using the example on that page though, could drawCircle of DrawingAPI1 call a public method in CircleShape?

Comment: You cannot call the public method of the caller directly, please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like D shouldn't extend C. An instance of D should instead have access to an instance that it can delegate to when needed. This delegate should be typed with an interface that you can have C implement. The interface will only include those methods D should be able to call. You inject an instance of this interface into D so it can do what it needs.

```
public interface Delegate {
    public String getInformation();
}

public class C implements Delegate {
    public String getInformation() {...}
    public void otherMethod();
    public void anotherOtherMethod();
}         

public class D {
    private Delegate delegate;

    public D(Delegate delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public void printSomething() {
        System.out.println(delegate.getInformation());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, this has gone a bit over my head.  Let me give a bit more example, and maybe you can further explain for me.  So Object A is a Team, Object B is a PlayerObject.  The PlayerObject stores info about the player that I need, and contains a reference to the actual Player(C).  D is a BaseBall Player, so it is a type of Player.  How can I make it so I can ask the player where he wants to move, but he can not actually move himself (to prevent cheating).  That is just a simplified example of roughly what I need to do.

Comment: In this case, you would have PlayerObject implement Delegate. Player+ (BaseballPlayer, etc.) would get an instance of PlayerObject. (Assuming that there's something from PlayerObject that Player+ needs to determine where it wants to move, but that Player+ shouldn't be able to call other PlayerObject methods.)